# What will be the execution time in Big O notation in fnB?

Tags: java, big-o

I got 2 functions and I need to find the execution time for both functions in Big O, however I am confuse on fnB

```
int fnA(int n){
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=n; i<j; j=j-2){
      sum += i*j;

 }
   return sum;
}
```

I got O(n^2) for fnA

```
int fnB(int n) {
  int sum =0;
  for(int size = 1; size<n; size=2*size){
    sum+=fnA(size);
  }
   return sum;
}
```

Since within the for loop in fnB, size increase exponentially. I am leaning fnB has an O(n^3). Am I correct, if not please correct me, thank you

Comment: Big-O notation is about computational complexity, not execution time.

Comment: For fnA, it is actually O(n). Your inner for loop will never execute.

Comment: Sorry, I made some mistakes on my code

Comment: `for(int j=0; i<j; j=j-2)` will never execute, are you sure it's not a typo? `i<j` will never be true.

Comment: I change it to j=n

Answer (score 1):

`fnA` has a running time of O(n<sup>2</sup>).

However, `fnB` has a running time of O(n<sup>2</sup>logn), since it has log<sub>2</sub>n iterations, and each iteration takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) time (it actually takes O(size<sup>2</sup>), but since `size` < `n`, we can bound it with O(n<sup>2</sup>)).

A more detailed explanation:

`fnA(n)` has `n` iterations in the outer loop and at most `n/2` iterations in the inner loop, which gives O(n<sup>2</sup>) upper bound. Since each iteration of `fnB(n)` calls `fnA(size)`, it takes O(size<sup>2</sup>) == O(n<sup>2</sup>) (since `size` < `n`).

Now, the loop of `fnB(n)` assigns the following values to `size` : 2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>1</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup>, ..., 2<sup>k</sup> where 2<sup>k</sup> <= n. Therefore the number of iterations is k <= log<sub>2</sub>n, and the upper bound of `fnB` is O(n<sup>2</sup>log<sub>2</sub>n).

Comment: Could you point out where is the logn iteration come from, shouldnt be 2^n instead?

Comment: @stevielol size gets the following values : 2^0, 2^1, 2^2, ..., 2^k where 2^k <= n (i.e.the number of iterations is k <= logn)

Comment: Just 1 more question , how do you get each iteration takes O(n^2) time? Sorry for this silly question

Comment: @stevielol It's an upper bound. fnA(n) has n iterations in the outer loop and at most n/2 iterations in the inner loop, which gives O(n^2) upper bound. Since each iteration of fnB calls fnA(size), it takes O(size^2) = O(n^2) (since size < n).

Comment: `fnA` is `O(n^2)`, agreed, but `fnB` is then `O(1^2) + O(2^2) + O(4^2) + ... + O(n^2)`, which reduces to `O(n^2)`, since all the lower squares becomes negligible as `n` moved towards infinity. --- E.g. if `n = 256`, then `log n` is 8, so if `fnB` was `O(n^2logn)` as you said, then it would be `O(n^2 * 32)`, but that's not true.

Comment: @Andreas I'll have to check your calculations later. The bound I gave is an upper bound. Perhaps it's possible to prove a tighter upper bound, as you did.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O notation can be used to represent time-complexity or space-complexity of an algorithm.

In your program, the function fnA can be thought of having a time complexity of O(n^2) because it has two nested `for` loops.  However, due to the condition `i<j` which always evaluates to false, the inner `for` loop would never execute. So the more realistic time-complexity of your `fnA` function is O(n).

Your `fnB` function calls `fnA` in a single `for` loop. Therefore, its time complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: I have edit my code, the outcome should be different now

Comment: Now the time-complexity is O(n^3).